# MUI-X DateRangePicker custom text field

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x, mui-x-date-picker

I am using `DateRangePicker` component where users can select `startDate` and `endDate`. Additionally, users should also be able to select the `time` for `startDate` and `endDate` as well. I am using `MultiSectionDigitalClock` to allow users to select the `Time`. The problem is, I can't update the `Time` correctly because I can't find a way to differentiate between the `textFields`. There are 2 `TextField` components and not sure which is `start` and which is `end`. Here is the code

```
const TriggerAndDigitalClock = ({
  dateRange,
  onChange,
  ...props
}: React.PropsWithChildren<TextFieldProps> & {
  onChange: (
    newDate: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<[Date | null, Date | null]>>,
  ) => void;
  dateRange: [Date | null, Date | null];
}) => {
  return (
    <Stack>
      <TextField {...props} />
      <MultiSectionDigitalClock
        value={dateRange[1]}
        onChange={(newDate) => onChange((pre) => [pre[0], newDate])}
      />
    </Stack>
  );
};
```

```
const DemoDateRangeAndTime = () => {
  const [dateRange, setDateRange] = useState<[Date | null, Date | null]>([
    new Date(),
    new Date(),
  ]);

  return (
    <DateRangePicker
      value={dateRange}
      onChange={setDateRange}
      slots={{
        // eslint-disable-next-line react/no-unstable-nested-components
        textField: (props) => (
          <TriggerAndDigitalClock
            {...props}
            onChange={setDateRange}
            dateRange={dateRange}
          />
        ),
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

**Current Behavior** : When the time is updated, both `Time`fields get updated.

**Expected Behavior** : `StartTimePicker` should only update the `StartTime`. So is `EndTime`

[image]

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question.